# Macro to replace many string constants

Tags: c, macros, constants

I have several labels for camera objects, and I am trying to save memory (very stingy memory environment). Here is my current version, using a static constant array and a macro:

In the header:

```
#define NUM_CAMERAS         6        
static const char* CAM_LABELS[NUM_CAMERAS] = {  "Camera1",
                                                "Camera2",
                                                "Camera3",
                                                "752x480_cam",
                                                "std_cam",
                                                "wide_cam" };
#define CAM_LABEL(id)           id<=NUM_CAMERAS?CAM_LABELS[id-1]:"cam id error"
```

Usage in the program:

```
int cam = 3;     
pritnf("Configuring camera id [%d], label: [%s]\n",cam, CAM_LABEL(cam) );
```

The above works, but I wanted to use macros to replace the static const array, so I would have something in the header more like:

```
#define NUM_CAMERAS       6
#define CAM_LABEL1        "Camera1"
#define CAM_LABEL2        "Camera2"
#define CAM_LABEL3        "Camera3"
#define CAM_LABEL4        "752x480_cam"
#define CAM_LABEL5        "std_cam"
#define CAM_LABEL6        "wide_cam"
#define CAM_LABEL(id)     /* myster code */
```

Is there some way to pass an integer value as 'id' above and then recreate a known CAM_LABEL## value? I tried a few combinations of the ## gluing macro, but it would put in "cam" or whatever variable name was passed into the macro, instead of that variables value. I've probably missed something very obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The value of `cam` is only available at runtime, macro expansion is before compile time, that's why it can't work that way.

Comment: I knew there was an obvious reason. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I understood your problem, but this works perfectly for me:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define CAM_LABEL1        "Camera1"
#define CAM_LABEL2        "Camera2"
#define CAM_LABEL3        "Camera3"
#define CAM_LABEL4        "752x480_cam"
#define CAM_LABEL5        "std_cam"
#define CAM_LABEL6        "wide_cam"

#define CAM(n) CAM_LABEL##n

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  printf("CAM: [%s], [%s]\n",CAM(2),CAM(3));
}
```

However, I don't think this would be effective to save memory (which seems your main concern).
You are counting on the fact that the compiler will collapse constant strings that are identical so that every instance of "Camera1" is replaced by the same pointer (and the string itself is stored only once). This is not guaranteed; in:

```
printf("%s, %s\n","Camera1","Camera1");
```

it is legitimate for the compiler to create TWO spearate strings.

I would suggest you to create a single string and an offset vector:

```
const char *cam_labels="Camera1\0Camera2\0Camera3";
const char *cam_labels_offset = "\x00\x08\x10";

#define CAM(x)    (cam_labels+cam_labels_offset[x])
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  printf("CAM: [%s], [%s]\n",CAM(0),CAM(2));
}
```

You should add some control to avoid nasty things to happen (but taking the risk of double evaluation) and if the total length of strings is more than 255 you will need to represent the offsets with two bytes.

You should also write a small routine to get the offsets, counting them by hand would be too error prone.

Let p be the size of a (char *) in your system, n the number of labels and s the sum of the length of the strings (including the ending \0).

Your first approach (the one with the array of pointers to strings) will need n*p+s bytes to store, your second approach (with macros) really depends on the compiler, the one I suggest will need  2p+s+n.